# Looking for a single line solution in Pandas / First time occurrence in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a single line of code that will provide the output of the time in which a certain instance occurred.
With the given DataFrame, please let me know how to create an output of the time when the 'high' value, for the first time (and only the first time), exceeded 3.35.
The correct answer would be 10:30:00, but I don't know how to produce a single line of pandas code that could produce this output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'time': ['2021-02-01 9:30:00', '2021-02-01 10:00:00', '2021-02-01 10:30:00', '2021-02-01 11:00:00','2021-02-01 11:30:00'], 'open': ['1.00', '2.00','3.00', '4.00','5.00'],
        'high': ['1.50','2.50','3.50','4.50','5.50']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('time')
```

Comment: Look into one of these options ... https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

This works if the values of 'high' are floats. It only gets the time of the first row matching your criterion, it does not mean time is the smallest value. That's only true if your dataframe is properly sorted:

```
df.loc[df[df['high'] > 3.35].index[0], 'time']
```

Comment: Also `df.loc[df['high'] > 3.35, 'time'].iloc[0]`?